# Slideshow - Pause show when hovering over thumbnail

Tags: javascript, slideshow, nivo-slider

The client has requested that when the viewer hovers over the thumbnails the slideshow automatically pauses. Is this possible? If so how do you do it as I'm a javascript newbie. The slideshow currently pauses when hovering over the main image.

It's the Nivo slider plugin for Wordpress which I purchased.

Thanks

[Paul Day Sculpture](http://temp.pauldaysculpture.com/artworks/largesculptures/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nivo-control').hover(function(){
vars.paused = true;
clearInterval(timer);
timer = '';
}, function(){
vars.paused = false;
// Restart the timer
if(timer === '' && !settings.manualAdvance){
timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
}
});
```

Add this code in jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js. it will work